# Native IIS7.5 Module not running

Tags: c++, http, http-headers, iis-7.5, ihttpmodule

I've created a simple `CHttpModule` that adds a custom header to all requests:

```
#define _WINSOCKAPI_
#include <windows.h>
#include <sal.h>
#include <httpserv.h>

class AppendHeaderModule : public CHttpModule {
public:
    REQUEST_NOTIFICATION_STATUS
        OnBeginRequest(
        IN IHttpContext * pHttpContext,
        IN IHttpEventProvider * pProvider
        )
    {
        UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(pProvider);

        PCSTR testHeaderName = "Foo";
        PCSTR testHeader = "bar";
        pHttpContext->GetResponse()->SetHeader(testHeaderName, testHeader, (USHORT)strlen(testHeader), true);

        return RQ_NOTIFICATION_CONTINUE;
    }

    VOID Terminate() {
        delete this;
    }

    AppendHeaderModule() { }
    ~AppendHeaderModule() { }
};

class AppendHeaderModuleFactory : public IHttpModuleFactory {
public:
    HRESULT
        GetHttpModule(
        OUT CHttpModule ** ppModule,
        IN IModuleAllocator * pAllocator
        )
    {
        UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(pAllocator);

        AppendHeaderModule* pModule = new AppendHeaderModule;

        if (!pModule) {
            return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY);
        }
        else {
            *ppModule = pModule;
            pModule = NULL;
            return S_OK;
        }
    }

    void Terminate() {
        delete this;
    }
};


HRESULT __stdcall
RegisterModule(
DWORD dwServerVersion,
IHttpModuleRegistrationInfo * pModuleInfo,
IHttpServer * pGlobalInfo
)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(dwServerVersion);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(pGlobalInfo);

    AppendHeaderModuleFactory* pModule = new AppendHeaderModuleFactory;
    if (pModule == NULL) 
        return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY);

    return pModuleInfo->SetRequestNotifications(pModule, RQ_BEGIN_REQUEST, 0);
}
```

I've copied it to `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv`, registered the module, and added it to the list.  However, I'm not seeing the additional header in any of my requests.  I created a similar managed module, installed it to the GAC, registered it, and it works fine.  But this native module seems to do nothing.  Is there another step required to get native modules to handle requests?

Also, I'm not sure if it matters, but the requests are being made to an ASP.NET site.  Do native handlers not run for ASP.NET?

Answer (score 0):

If the module is a 32-bit module you need to enable 32-bit applications in the application pool for your website. Go to the Application Pools, select the pool for your website, Advanced Settings and set "Enable 32-Bit Applications to TRUE.